# should questions closed as being off topic / better intended for expats be auto moved to expats?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

I was looking at [*Urgent* American citizen studying in the UK. Flight leaves tomorrow, visa in processing and no biometrics?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/55559/4868) and wondered...  maybe that should be auto-moved to expats instead of just being closed and the OP told to repost the question on expats?

Comment: Not sure if duplicate or related.

Comment: I personally think that question is fine here, he's not asking about being an expat, he's asking about entering as a tourist. *shrug*.

Comment: @MarkMayo That's debatable, that's about travelling to the UK in any case but the OP does not intend to actually visit as a tourist and return to the US, only to enter (ostensibly as a visitor) and start his studies. He is even asking about completing the long-stay visa formalities in the UK (the bit about biometrics).

Comment: @Relaxed ah, good point. yeah it's a bit in both camps, can see why it was closed.

Comment: ^ another reason (imo) that travel and expats should be merged

Answer (score 3):

The current situation is far from ideal because many posters will be tempted to cross-post in the meantime and we sometimes end up with two identical questions on expats but I believe this is not possible (on a technical level) as long as expats is in beta. The only solution is to flag the question and wait for a moderator to take care of it.

I think we discussed this some time ago, incidentally, but I can't find where.

Comment: Also, auto-migration to sites in beta is generally done done (I read this as a 'rule' somewhere, can't find it now)